# Why doesn't `mix` pull this transitive dependency?

Tags: elixir

[exsync](https://github.com/falood/exsync) has a dependency [exfswatch](https://github.com/falood/exfswatch) that has a dependency [fs](https://github.com/synrc/fs).

If I run `mix deps.get` in `exsync`, `fs` is not pulled. If I run `mix deps.get` in `exfswatch`, it **is** pulled. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hex packages can depend only on other hex packages. The `fs` package is pulled in as a git dependency. For hex the `exfswatch` package does not depend on `fs` - there's a huge warning where you're publishing such a package to hex.

Comment: What about git? Can `mix` pull a chain of strictly git dependencies?

Comment: Yes, mix can pull git dependencies, it's only the case of hex packages that can't depend on anything other than hex packages. If that wasn't the case it would be really hard to guarantee reproducible builds.